# GTK# - Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, gtk, gtk3

I created a simple gtk application using GTK# for Windows (Gtk# 2.99.3).

During the view creation and deletion I found a memory leak. So I wrote a simple application to verify this:

```
        private static void MemoryTest()
    {
        //Create the view
        Gtk.Builder builder = new Gtk.Builder(null, "Modules.Dashboard.Dashboard.ui", null);


        //Create the parameters
        object[] parameters = new object[3] { builder, builder.GetObject("window1").Handle, 0 };
        //Load the current view
        var view = (ViewBase)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DashboardView), parameters);


        //TRY TO DESTROY;
        view.Destroy();
        builder.Dispose();

        view.Dispose();
    }
```

The function is called 10000 times:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            MemoryTest();
        Console.WriteLine("Run GC");
        System.GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Default, true);

        Console.WriteLine("Finsih GC");

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            MemoryTest();
```

During the execution of this application the requiered memory increase constantly.

Are the futher steps required to delete the whole window?

My .ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkGrid" id="view">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="row_homogeneous">True</property>
        <property name="column_homogeneous">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Ich</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
            <property name="width">1</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">bin</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">1</property>
            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
            <property name="width">1</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label3">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">ein</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">1</property>
            <property name="width">1</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label4">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Dashboard</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">1</property>
            <property name="top_attach">1</property>
            <property name="width">1</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: GtkWindows (and only GtkWindows) created with `builder.GetObject()` become your responsibility to destroy; GtkBuilder creates another reference to the window for you. See [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html).

Comment: I tried to change my code in the following way
`var window1 = builder.GetObject("window1");
object[] parameters = new object[3] { builder, window1.Handle, 0 };
....
//TRY TO DESTROY;
view.Destroy();
builder.Dispose();

view.Dispose();
window1.Dispose();`

But I run into the same problem. The memory is still increasing ....

Comment: Are you leaking that object array too?

Comment: I don't think so. I checked it with the .net Memory Profiler.
 
As far I can see, the object array doesn't leak. 
The second strange behavoir is, that the memory is still increasing during the program run, but the .net memory Profiler shows only one instance of the Dashboard view. 

So in my opinion the view class is destroyed, but some of the gtk function still hold something in the memory.